# Why does my onClickOutside function disables the click on links from other components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tsx

I have a custom React Hook where if user clicks outside of the element it triggers a function. It works, but when I click on a link from a parent component it does not work. But if the link is in the same component this works. Does someone have a solution?

This is my code:

onClickOutside hook

```
type Event = MouseEvent | TouchEvent

const useClickOutside = <T extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement>(
    ref: RefObject<T>,
    handler: (event: Event) => void
) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const listener = (e: Event) => {
            const el = ref?.current
            if (!el || el.contains((e?.target as Node) || null)) {
                return
            }

            handler(e)
        }

        document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener)
        document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener)

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener)
            document.removeEventListener("touchstart", listener)
        }
    }, [ref, handler])
}
```

Parent component:

```
const ParentComponent = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </nav>

            {children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Child component:

```
const ChildComponent = () => {
    const ref = useRef(null);
    useClickOutside(ref, onClickOutside)

    return (
        <ParentComponent>
            ...rest of the page
            <button ref={ref}>
                Click me
            </button>
        </ParentComponent>
    )
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
const target = e.target as any;
if (target.getAttribute("href"))
    return false;
```